# Unable to set any ACL on an anonymous object in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I've got an S3 bucket owned by the root AWS account.

A subdirectory of the bucket called `uploads` is open to the world, that is (at the bucket level):

```
{
    "Sid": "Allow anonymous uploads",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/uploads/*"
}
```

When I upload a file as an anonymous user (not providing any AWS credentials), I can indeed write to the `uploads` directory. However neither an IAM user nor the parent (root) user is able to apply any modification to the uploaded files such as renaming or moving, and the problem occurs regardless of the interface used, AWS console or the API.

The anonymous objects are uploaded using `POST` and the parameter

`'acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control'` or alternatively `'acl': 'public-read-write'`

Is it possible that ACL policies, even when they are explicitly mentioned in the upload parameters, have no impact on objects with no owner (uploaded by anonymous)? If that is the case, is there a way to change the ownership of a file upon upload or retroactively?

**Why isn't the ACL policy taken into account when the file is uploaded?**

**Why can't I rename or move the uploaded files?**

---

### Additional information

The POST request is made by a cordova plugin named [`FileTransfer`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) which uses `POST` by default but can use `PUT` if needed. Here is the piece of code that performs the upload:

```
        var upload_options = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Length': 4900000,
                'Connection': 'close',
                'acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control'
            },
            params: {
                'key': 'uploads/' + fileName,
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        };
        var s3 = new FileTransfer();
        s3.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://<my-bucket>.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"), upload_success, upload_fail, upload_options);
```

Comment: Amend the policy statement to add `"Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": [
            "bucket-owner-full-control"
          ]
        }
      }` and you may have your answer -- your upload may be doing something that causes the ACL not to be set, and this will only allow uploads where it is set.

Comment: I just tried with the condition applied and this leads to the upload being denied (AccessDenied). So that means the POST request is badly built somehow.

Comment: Wait, `POST`?  Show the code that's doing the upload.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  I just updated the question. Do you think using `PUT` with `x-amz-acl` instead of `POST` and  the `acl` header would help? I'm trying this out in the meantime.

Comment: Just tried with forced `PUT` method and using the `x-amz-acl` header and I'm getting `MalformedXML` "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema". So I fear I'll have to dig into the code of `FileTransfer` to see what it does under the hood...

Comment: Heh I think you just tried to `PUT /` instead of `PUT /${key}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131517/discussion-between-buddyshot-and-michael-sqlbot).